# Images in my Joomla template

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla, joomla-sef-urls, joomla-template

I created a Joomla template by creating the following files:**index.php**" , "**templateDetails.xml**","**images**" and "**css**". I installed it correctly but the images are not displayed when i am selecting the template.

Anyone knows how to resolve this problem? I triple checked the paths and different settings of Joomla but i did not work

---

**This is part of the XML file that corresponds to images**

```
            <filename>images/left-top-corner.png</filename>
            <filename>images/main-banner.jpg</filename>
            <filename>images/main-bg.jpg</filename>
            <filename>images/menu-bg.gif</filename>
            <filename>images/right-bot-corner.png</filename>
            <filename>images/right-top-corner.png</filename>
```

**This is part of the CSS code**

- `{ margin:0; padding:0;}
  html, body { height:100%;}
  body { background:url(..\images\main-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top #efc072; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:100%; line-height:1.0625em; color:#968a70;}`

**This is part of the basic index.php**

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />`
baseurl ?>/templates/mynewtemplate/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
baseurl ?>/templates/mynewtemplate/css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
baseurl ?>/templates/mynewtemplate/css/ie_style.css" type="text/css" />
baseurl ?>/templates/template?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" />

baseurl ?>/templates/template;?>/css/ie_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    
        baseurl ?>/templates/template;?>/css/ie7only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    baseurl ?>/templates/template;?>/javascript/ie_png.js">

Comment: Please show an example path to an image that doesn't work, and (if you know it) the expected path

Comment: An example of the path I used e.g. [../images/submit-bg.gif]

Answer (score 1):

Did you find the problem? Looking at your CSS code I found a potential issue:

```
background:url(..\images\main-bg.jpg)
```

I think you should use normal slashes not the Windows style back slashes! Try the following:

```
background:url(../images/main-bg.jpg)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get @user480778 to respond to my answer?